# Best way to create dataframe from multiple nested lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance, dataframe

I have 4 nested list with the following structure:

```
liste 1 = [[ColA,ColB,ColC],.....]  
liste 2 = [[ColA,ColB,ColD],.....]  
liste 3 = [[ColA,ColB,ColE],.....]  
liste 4 = [[ColA,ColB,ColF],.....]
```

There are 2 columns in common. I want to create a single dataframe witht the following structure:

```
df.columns = [ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE,ColF]
```

What I did so far :

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame(list1,columns=['ColA','ColB','ColC'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2,columns=['ColA','ColB','ColD'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list3,columns=['ColA','ColB','ColE'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(list4,columns=['ColA','ColB','ColF'])


print('merging dataframes')
#dirty line to execute several outer join on multiple df in one line
df_Total=df1.merge(df2,how='left',on=['ColA','ColB']).merge(df3,how='left',on=['ColA','ColB']).merge(df4,how='left',on=['ColA','ColB'])
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to perform this in order to increase performances. 
I also tried the join method for the merger of my dataframes. I think the main improvement would be to create the correct df from the lists directly without creating 4 to then merge them together.

Comment: is the data inside the nested loops is in lists? or on standart: [['A', 'B'], [1,2]]? or [['A', 'B'], 1,2]

Comment: Nested lists (1st porposition), and there is no headers in the lists, that's why I specify the column name in the df creation